# of the form vs in the form

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> 1. The structure is of the form of X.
> 2. The structure is in the form of X.

What is the difference in meaning and which one is grammatically correct?

I think 1 means the structure is united with the form of X and 2 means the structure is shaped in the form of X

So, as for 1, I don't think the entire shape of the structure must look in the form of X (maybe ,part of it is united with the form of X?), but as for 2, I do think the entire shape of the structure must look in the form of X.

I wonder whether my thinking is correct.

Comment: The form structure is X. The structure of the form is x. This is really just editing.

Answer (score 1):

"In the form" and "of the form" - both phrases indicate a similarity or resemblance to something else, but the former refers to the physical appearance or shape, while the latter refers to the overall characteristics or nature.

"In the form of something" means that something is presented or expressed in a particular way or shape. For example, "The cake was in the form of a heart."

"Of the form of something" means that something is similar to or has the characteristics of something else. For example, "The sculpture was of the form of a human figure."

Answer (score 0):

> The structure is of the form of X.

This means that the object is partially or may be totally as X. Note that this covers both the possibilities.

E.g. The cave is of the form of a tavern.

> The structure is in the form of X.

This means that the whole object or the whole structure of the object is same to same as that of X. That means it is totally inspired by the X.

E.g. The cake is in the form of a Barbie Doll.

Comment: That first one is not idiomatic at all.